# Django Model Form clean method not being called

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have used a Django model form to create HackathonTeam instances. The issue I am facing here is that custom clean method that I have used is not being called. All the other default validations are happening correctly.

```
# models.py
class HackathonTeam(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    leader = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='leader_teams')
    hackathon = models.ForeignKey(Hackathon, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='hack_teams')
    vacancies = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    current_members = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name='member_teams')
    skills_required = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, related_name='hack_requirements')
    cutoff_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)  # Someone may not wish to have a cut-off date
    closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

# forms.py ########
class HackathonTeamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = HackathonTeam
        exclude = ['leader', 'current_members', 'closed']

    def clean(self):
        print("Inside clean")
        cleaned_data = super(HackathonTeamForm, self).clean()
        print(cleaned_data)
        if HackathonTeam.objects.filter(hackathon=cleaned_data.get("hackathon"),
                                        name=cleaned_data.get("name")).exists():
            print(1)
            raise forms.ValidationError("A team with the same name already exists.")
        return cleaned_data

# views.py #########

@login_required(login_url='users:login')
def add_hackathon_team(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = HackathonTeamForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.clean()
            print(cd)
            print("Data is valid")
            # form.save()
            team = form.save(commit=False)
            team.leader = request.user
            team.save()
            return redirect('users:view_hackathon_team', pk=team.id)
    else:
        form = HackathonTeamForm()
    return render(request, 'users/add_hackathon_team.html', {'form': form})
```

The print statement in the view is being printed and new Teams are created as well. The only issue is that the clean method is not called and duplicate Teams can be created as well.

Comment: Are you sure the clean method is not being called? Are "Inside clean" or "1" being printed?

Comment: (Also note, you actually cause that method to be called twice; you shouldn't call it directly, you should access the clean data via `form.cleaned_data`.

Comment: No, "Data is valid" is printed due to the view, but "Inside clean" or "1" are not printed to the console. Also, the reason I am calling the method again is to try and explicitly call clean and see which method is called. Even that did not work.

Comment: The only think I can think is that the indentation of the form is not as you have posted here - could `clean` be actually inside `Meta`?

Comment: Yeah, sorry Daniel. It was a stupid mistake on my part. It was the indentation. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

inside HackathonTeamForm class add the init function:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(HackathonTeamForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

you should use self.cleaned_data['field_name'] instead of (to make sure its not causing the problem, since you arent calling super maybe the fields are blank) :

```
cleaned_data = super(HackathonTeamForm, self).clean()
```

Comment: I added the init method and it did not make any difference. I am calling the super clean method in the code.